# Big Nerd Ranch, chapter 19, Avoiding strong reference cycle by reassigning pointers

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers

I am going through Big Nerd Ranch iOS textbook, 19th chapter and it is unclear for me why they are doing reassignment of pointers there to avoid strong reference cycle. Basically they have a block of code, `actionBlock` that has a strong reference to the class, `BNRItemCell`, and the reference persists beyond the life of the block. `BNRItemCell` is referencing the block through `@property`: `@property (strong, nonatomic) void (^actionBlock)(void)`. Obviously that creates strong reference cycle. To avoid it they define a `__weak BNRItemCell *weakCell = cell` outside of the block, and then `BNRItemCell *strongCell = weakCell` inside the block. They say that `strongCell` should persist while the block is executing and that it will be destroyed when the block is finished. I do not understand the reassignment within the block, `BNRItemCell *strongCell = weakCell`, and what is the point of the pointer being `__weak`. If, say, we do just `BNRItemCell *strongCell = cell`, where `cell` is the strong reference to the class, shouldn't it be OK? `strongCell` would still be destroyed when the block has finished executing.

I tried to visualize what is going on and what they are doing does not make sense for me. To make things clear, what is the difference between

```
__weak someClass *weakPointer = strongPointer_1;

someObject.actionBlock = ^{
someClass *strongPointer_2 = weakPoiter;
// Here we are using strongPointer_2
}
```

and

```
someObject.actionBlock = ^{
someClass *strongPointer_2 = strongPointer_1;
// Here we are using strongPointer_2
}
```

?

I just can not get the difference, so I guess, I do not have clear understanding of what is going on behind the scenes.

The full code is below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Get a new or recycled cell
BNRItemCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BNRItemCell"
                                forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Set the text on the cell with the description of the item
// that is the nth index of items, where n = row this cell
// will appear in on the tableview
NSArray *items = [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems];
BNRItem *item = items[indexPath.row];

// Configure the cell with the BNRItem
cell.nameLabel.text = item.itemName;
cell.serialNumberLabel.text = item.serialNumber;
cell.valueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%d", item.valueInDollars];

cell.thumbnailView.image = item.thumbnail;

__weak BNRItemCell *weakCell = cell;

cell.actionBlock = ^{
    NSLog(@"Going to show image for %@", item);

    BNRItemCell *strongCell = weakCell;

    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        NSString *itemKey = item.itemKey;

        // if there is no image, we don't need to display anything
        UIImage *img = [[BNRImageStore sharedStore] imageForKey:itemKey];
        if (!img) {
            return;
        }

        BNRImageViewController *ivc = [[BNRImageViewController alloc] init];
        ivc.image = img;

        ivc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
        ivc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(380, 300);
        CGRect frame = [self.view convertRect:strongCell.thumbnailView.bounds
                                     toView:self.view];
        // frame.origin.y -= 150;

        UIPopoverPresentationController *popoverController = ivc.popoverPresentationController;
        popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
        popoverController.sourceView = cell.thumbnailView;
        popoverController.sourceRect = frame;

        [self.navigationController presentViewController:ivc animated:YES completion:nil];


    }
};

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand why the "normal" case of capturing `self` or some other reference in a block causes a retain cycle.

If you have an instance variable holding a strong reference to a block, that block won't be dealloc'd until that reference is `nil`ed.  If the block captures a strong reference to the instance which references the block, that instance won't be `dealloc`ed until that reference is `nil`ed.  If both the instance and the block hold these references at the same time, you have your classic loop, unless one explicitly `nil`s its reference to the other.

The key thing here is that the block's reference to the class instance is held in the capture data.  This data sticks around as long as the block does.

Now we can see why capturing a weak pointer will help.  If the problem is the capture data, and not the references in the block itself, a weak pointer takes care of our cycle rather nicely.  The class instance can now be `dealloc`ed independently of the block, because the block has no strong reference.

Now the question is, why have a strong reference within the body of the block itself?  This is simply to make sure the instance won't be `dealloc`ed while the block is executing.  This isn't a real concern for stuff that is all running on the main thread, but that block might be dispatching to a background thread.

Why doesn't this (re)create a retain cycle?  Well, it does, but only temporarily.  The strong reference inside the block captures the weak pointer, which can be `nil`ed.  The strong reference is a block-scoped variable that will be cleaned up when the block exits.  ARC ensures that such references are `release`d before the return from the block, thereby stopping the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this correctly, it looks like they are trying to prevent a retain cycle.

```
__weak BNRItemCell *weakCell = cell;

cell.actionBlock = ^{
    BNRItemCell *strongCell = weakCell; // weakCell is captured here at block declaration time
}
```

Blocks capture and retain variable values, so if it captured a strong `BNRItemCell` (reference to itself), its strongly retained `actionBlock` would create a retain cycle. By capturing the `BNRItemCell` as weak, if the table view ever decided to discard the cell, your cell will be properly deallocated.

---

If it helps you, think about how many strong references exist to the `BNRItemCell`. The table view keeps a strong reference (+1) while the cell is on screen. By capturing a strong reference (+1) in the `actionBlock`, you'd have brought its reference count up to 2.

An object will remain in memory as long as its reference count is 1 or more. So even if the `UITableView` releases its reference to the cell, you've still got the reference in its `actionBlock`, which will keep its reference count positive. Since you never set `actionBlock = nil` (which you shouldn't), `actionBlock` will never get released, and therefore the `BNRItemCell` never will either.

---

Note that `weakCell` is the only captured value at block creation time, `strongCell` won't even exist until the block is actually called.

---

**TL;DR:** The cell would be keeping a strong reference to itself through its `actionBlock`, which would create a retain cycle.

Comment: But is not `BNRItemCell *strongCell = weakCell` creating strong reference to the `cell`? I just visualize the situation with pointers, and for me it seems that there is no real difference between assigning `strongCell` directly to the `cell` or through the `weakCell` because these are just pointers. Do you mean that the block itself will behave differently because of some (unknown to me) Objective C conventions? I understand how the reference system works, that's not my question here.

Comment: In both cases, it seems to me, `strongCell` would point to the `cell`, and what is the difference then?

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko Ah, that _is_ is creating a strong reference to cell, but not until the block is actually called. (`weakCell` is captured at block declaration, but thats all that happens until its called)

Comment: OK, in both cases strong reference to the `cell` is created. I still can not get why we are declaring `__weak BNRItemCell *weakCell = cell;`

Comment: A "weak" reference must be created outside the `actionBlock` so that when the `actionBlock` captures the `weakCell` variable, it will be capturing a weak reference and won't create a retain cycle.

Comment: OK, I see, thank you! When I started to think of what happens when the cell gets deallocated, it really helped to get what you are trying to say.

Comment: Glad I could help @NikitaVlasenko

Comment: Sorry, I actually thought it over, and I can not get it still. From my understanding a pointer to `cell` stores the address of the `cell`. `weakCell` stores the address of the `cell` and the system is informed by `weak` that it can be destroyed when the respective `cell` is destroyed. Inside the block we have `strongCell` that stores the address of the `cell`, but not the address of the `weakCell`, am I right? Then, it does not make sense. Could you please, if you can, clarify what is going on with pointers when the `cell` gets deallocated on a very low level, with addresses?

Comment: I reread the answer several times and it does not answer my question.

Comment: if the cell is ever discarded, it will not be properly removed because, in my understanding, `strongCell` stores the reference to the `cell`, but not to the `weakCell`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95505/discussion-between-santa-claus-and-nikita-vlasenko).

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko if this answered your question, don't forget to accept it. If you need anything else clarified, feel free to ping me in chat (type @Santa)

Comment: The upper one is answering my question, not this one. I was suspecting that some "third party" participates in the process, and @Avi really speaks about it: `The key thing here is that the block's reference to the class instance is held in the capture data. This data sticks around as long as the block does.`

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't even see that answer my bad (the stack exchange app scrolled past it) @NikitaVlasenko